# Корректировка значения при запросах SELECT UPDATE INSERT

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core

Есть в системе некоторые свойства сущности, числа с плавающей точкой, хранящееся в БД. Так же в настройках системы есть коэффициент. При выводе реальное значение должно умножаться на коэффициент, а при вводе делиться.

Первое, что приходит в голову, сделать это на точках входа (REST), но клинтов несколько + межсервисное взаимодействие и по некоторым причинам точки входа разные. В итоге есть риск забыть про коэффициент, что приведет к порче данных. Поэтому, хочу сделать это под капотом при сохранении / чтении. ORM - Entity Framework Core 2.2

Все еще усложняется текстовым поиском по этим полям на вхождение. То есть пользователь вводит строку "1.1" и должен получить в тч строку со значением "11.12". Для достижения этого значение перед сравнением приводится к строке. Но с коэффициентом все сложнее. Реально в базе хранится не "11.12", а "0.1112". То есть приведение на слое инфраструктуры не подходит, нужно именно на слое БД.

Подскажите способ пожалуйста.

Comment: Обычно в таких случаях прямой доступ к таблицам не дают, а используют процедуры/функции и т.д. и в них уже делают логику с преобразованием и поиском данных. В таблицах лучше хранить сырые данные и коэффициент умножения тоже где-то хранить, а логику умножений-делений пусть процедуры реализуют, иначе очередное приложение и правда легко может забыть сделать нужное преобразование данных при записи/чтении в БД.

Comment: @CrazyElf Не уверен, что процедуры в данном случае хорошая идея. Они, скорее, для вспомогательных действий над данными и схемой, а не для бизнес логики. Хотя, это вкусовщина.